# Fabric.js Using ellipses as clipping shape

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, mask, clipping

Im a bit struggling with getting ellipses to work in fabric.js.
Which then I would like to use it as clipping.

for normal rectangle

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, (asset) => {
   left: 0,
   right: 0,
   scaleX: 100 / asset.width,
   height: 100 / asset.height,
   clipTo: function(ctx) {
     ctx.save();
     ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
     ctx.rect(0,0, 100, 100);
     ctx.stroke();
     ctx.restore();
   }
});
```

I find it awesome that it allows out of the box to move the image within the clipping mask. I would like to do this also with an ellipses but having a difficult time to get it to work. I already tried it with an arc and the scale it but then the content will scale with it.

I'm also curious to find out if it is possible to do something like this.
Which I couldn't get it  to work.

```
fabric.Ellipses({
    left:100,
    top: 100,
    stroke: 'black',
    fill: 'white',
    selectable: true,
    originX: 'center', 
    originY: 'center',
    rx: 50,
    ry: 100
});

asset.clipTo(ctx) => {
   asset.render(ctx);
}
```

Or maybe a different way...

Comment: can you post the actual code you used?